# Comparison/Review Website Software

Tags: php, .net, mysql, sql, comparison

I am looking for website software (preferably open source), written in either PHP or ASP.net, where users can login and review a certain place and compare it against others in the area. Does anyone know of any that exist?

Comment: Any particular kind of place? E.g. restaurants, bars, hotels ....

Comment: It will be for Restaurants/Bars but potentially looking for an engine that can be expanded to other things